# Derivative of matrix function

Tags: linear-algebra

$y,b$ are vectors: y $\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, b $\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a matrix.
What do I misunderstand here?

$$ \frac{d}{db}(y-Xb)^{2} = $$
$$ 2(y-Xb) * \frac{d}{db}(y-Xb) = $$
$$ 2(y-Xb) * - X = $$
$$ -2X(y-Xb)$$

But it should be $-2X^\top(y-Xb)$

How does this work? Thanks!

Comment: How do you define $\frac{d}{db}$ when $b$ is a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that if $v$ is a vector, then $v^2$ does not make sense. However, $v\cdot v=v^T v$ does make sense. Let $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $y\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then $y-Xb\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $\frac{d}{db}(y-Xb)^T(y-Xb)=-2{X^T}_{n\times m}(y-Xb)_{m\times 1}$. In your answer the product between the matrix and the vector $y-Xb$ is not defined.

Comment: sorry y and b are of the same size, I edit my question

Comment: but what rule does it say that it has to be transposed?

Comment: oh,,, now i see, when i move the matrix forward that is the wrong step! thanks